# Facebook not showing "add friend"

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Facebook wasn't showing the "add friend" button to my profile and instead showed "follow". How can I get the add friend to show? Also I want to double check that non-friends can search me, what are the settings?

Answer (score 1):

Sign into Facebook. At the top, click on the picture of the lock between your name and the gear icon. Click "who can contact me?" and under "who can send me friend requests?" choose "everyone".